# VSTS build and release error

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Hi I am trying to catch CICD process with VSTS. Currently I can use git based code repository. However I wonder that I stuck with .net build parameters. Also some errors like below.
Can somebody help me to resolved this.

VSTS build error click here:

[image]

[Click this link - Details for error tasks. Note: I have No reputation over here so cannot upload direct image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QCni.png)

[image]

Comment: In your Visual Studio you succeed to compile the code?

Comment: Yes I do succeed in Visual Studio. VS 2015

Comment: If you run your project with MSBuild command line manually, how's the result? Could you share the detailed build log?

Comment: It works perfectly. Without any error. I am putting details snap as per you said. Please check new edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to your DLL files. Can you please add .dll to gitignore (in case you are using git) This should not include current working obj/debug/*. Try this. Hope this will help. Please share if there is ! mark over DIYRR.dll in VS.